# modifying Word document margin on many documents

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010

I have plenty of Word documents. I want to modify the page margin on each of them.

Is there any way of doing this? 
Either using the template or the styles?

What I tried :

1. Create a template with the new margin sizes
2. Save the template
3. Open the document, and using the developper ribbon, attach the new created template

But it doesn't work. The margin do not seem to be altered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The feature you are trying to use is called **Automatically update styles** and copies all of the style information from newly attached template and uses it to override the existing styles in the document. I'm afraid it doesn't work for page setup as this is based on section formatting and not styles.

I can't think of any way to achieve this using templates either so a macro would be the way to go.

Comment: A macro sounds like a good option, or if you have any software developers working with/for you have them see if it's possible using Word Automation in .NET

Comment: Indeed, only way is using Macro. Thanks for the input.